# Unbound DataGridView not displaying added row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a VB application I'm working on that uses DataGridViews to display data of various types. The application has separate forms to create new records for each of the tables displayed in the DataGridViews. The data passing works correctly (the application stores the data in flat files when it closes and those have everything they should).

I recently pulled some code from the Visible_Changed event that handled passing the data from the fields on the entry form to the display. It was the exact same code, just invoked specifically by the entry forms' Save buttons rather than the Visible_Changed event on the display form (which was creating headaches around over invoking and creating a need for variables to block execution of some code depending on why the form was becoming visible/invisible).

After that change, the data still seems to be passing correctly (I have Checked_List_Views that serve as filters for the DataGridView, and they're seeing the new items), but the item doesn't display. I previously had this issue with the old code and had resolved it by adding `Msr_List.Refresh` to force the grid to refresh. That doesn't seem to be having the same impact now though. Any ideas on how to get the DataGridView to actually update to include the new item would be appreciated.

Here's the old code:

```
Private Sub Form_Visibility_Change(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.VisibleChanged
    '
    Dim Sort_Col As DataGridViewColumn = Nothing
    Dim Need_Statuses As Boolean = True

    'Check if Add_Edit_Status is blank, if so no action needed
    Select Case UCase(New_Edit_Status)

        'Determine what form we just came back from (NOTE: The Create Statuses button doesn't leave this form so this Sub isn't invoked by it, thus that case isn't listed)
        Case "", "CANCEL", "OUTBOUND"
            'Do nothing
        Case "SAVE-NEW_MSR"
            'How to proceed?
            If Not IsNothing(Target_Row) Then
                'Prevent creation of bogus status records
                Need_Statuses = False
                Try
                    'Delete the current version. This way the normal Add step covers both cases
                    Msr_List.Rows.Remove(Target_Row)
                    Target_Row = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Encountered an error while removing the old version of a measure. Due to the potentially dire consequences of this error, the program" _
                           & " will now close. The HEDIS Measure XML should be restored from backup. Please see the error log for more details.", _
                           vbOKOnly, "Critical Measure List Management Error")
                    MWin.Err.AddErr("Encountered an error while removing the old version of a measure that was updated. Details: " & ex.Message _
                                    & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & ex.InnerException.Message, MWin.Err_Path & MWin.Err.DStamp & MWin.Log_Name)
                    MWin.Close()
                End Try
            End If 'else we're adding a new population so just proceed to adding the list row

            'Add the new row/version of the row
            Try
                Msr_List.Rows.Add(New_Msr_Form.Msr_ID.Text, New_Msr_Form.Msr_Name.Text, New_Msr_Form.SubMsr_Name.Text, New_Msr_Form.Msr_Key.Text, _
                                  New_Msr_Form.SubMsr_Key.Text, New_Msr_Form.Spec_Section.Text, New_Msr_Form.Complexity.Text, New_Msr_Form.Spec_Yr_Created.Text, _
                                  New_Msr_Form.Spec_Yr_Removed.Text, New_Msr_Form.Denom_Only.Checked, New_Msr_Form.Report_Medicaid.Checked, _
                                  New_Msr_Form.Report_Medicare.Checked, New_Msr_Form.Report_Ambetter.Checked)

                Msr_List.Refresh()
                Refresh()
                'Update form variables
                New_Edit_Status = ""
                Msrs_Changed = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Encountered an error while creating the new version of an update measure. Due to the potentially dire consequences of this" _
                       & "error, the program will now close. The HEDIS Measure XML should be restored from backup. Please see the error log for " _
                       & "more details.", vbOKOnly, "Updated Measure Creation Error")
                MWin.Err.AddErr("Encountered an error while adding a new row to the QSI Populations DataGridView. Details: " & ex.Message, _
                                MWin.Err_Path & MWin.Err.DStamp & MWin.Log_Name)
                MWin.Close()
            End Try

            'Push the data back to the data table
            Fill_Tbl_From_List(Msr_List, MWin.HEDIS_Msr_List_Tbl, "Msr_List_View", MWin)

            'Create statuses if needed
            If Need_Statuses Then
                Create_Statuses(New_Msr_Form.Spec_Yr_Created.Text, New_Msr_Form.Msr_ID.Text, MWin)
            End If 'else nothing needs done

            'Re-sort
            Try
                Sort_Col = Msr_List.Columns("Msr_ID")
                Msr_List.Sort(Sort_Col, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Encountered an error trying re-sort the updated HEDIS Measures list to properly place the new/updated row. This is" _
                       & " non-critical so the program will continue, but an error log entry has been created with more details.", vbOKOnly, _
                       "Measure List Sort Error")
                MWin.Err.AddErr("Encountered an error while trying to sort the QSI Populations DataGridView. Details: " & ex.Message & _
                                Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Inner Exception: " & ex.InnerException.Message, MWin.Err_Path & MWin.Err.DStamp & MWin.Log_Name)
            End Try

        Case "SAVE-NEW_BENCH"
            'Create the record in the benchmark history data table
            MWin.Benchmarking_Hist.Rows.Add(New_Bench.Msr_ID.Text, New_Bench.Population.Text, New_Bench.Spec_Yr.Text)

            'Reset New_Edit_Status
            New_Edit_Status = ""
            New_Bench = Nothing

        Case Else
            MsgBox("Encountered error while handling the HEDIS Measure List Viewer becoming visible. A bad New_Edit_Status was passed, specifically '" & _
                   New_Edit_Status & "'. This will mean some data may be lost & the form will act as though it's opening from the Main Window.", vbOKOnly, _
                   "Unknown New_Edit_Status")
            MWin.Err.AddErr("Unhandled return from QSI Add/Edit form to QSI Population Viewer form of '" & New_Edit_Status & _
                            "'. Please address this return value.", MWin.Err_Path & MWin.Err.DStamp & MWin.Log_Name)
            New_Edit_Status = ""

    End Select

    'Check if we should enable the Edit btn
    If Msr_List.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Edit_Btn.Enabled = True
    Else
        Edit_Btn.Enabled = False
    End If

    'Dispose of the form
    If Not (IsNothing(New_Msr_Form)) And New_Edit_Status <> "Outbound" Then
        New_Msr_Form = Nothing
    End If 'else no form to dispose of
End Sub
```

`Msr_List` is the DataGridView, `New_Msr_Form` is the data entry form, `Target_Row` is the selected row of the DataGridView (if any, limited to selecting one row), `New_Edit_Status` is the clunky way I was letting the display form know whether the new entry was successful or not. Obviously not ideal, but it (mostly) worked.

Here's the new code:

```
Public Sub Successful_New_Msr()
    '
    Dim Sort_Col As DataGridViewColumn = Nothing
    Dim Need_Statuses As Boolean = True

    'How to proceed?
    If Not IsNothing(Target_Row) Then
        'Prevent creation of bogus status records
        Need_Statuses = False
        Try
            'Delete the current version. This way the normal Add step covers both cases
            Msr_List.Rows.Remove(Target_Row)
            Target_Row = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Encountered an error while removing the old version of a measure. Due to the potentially dire consequences of this error, the program" _
                   & " will now close. The HEDIS Measure XML should be restored from backup. Please see the error log for more details.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Critical Measure List Management Error")
            MWin.Err.AddErr("Encountered an error while removing the old version of a measure that was updated. Details: " & ex.Message _
                            & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & ex.InnerException.Message, MWin.Err_Path & MWin.Err.DStamp & MWin.Log_Name)
            MWin.Close()
        End Try
    End If 'else we're adding a new population so just proceed to adding the list row

    'Add the new row/version of the row
    Try
        Msr_List.Rows.Add(New_Msr_Form.Msr_ID.Text, New_Msr_Form.Msr_Name.Text, New_Msr_Form.SubMsr_Name.Text, New_Msr_Form.Msr_Key.Text, _
                          New_Msr_Form.SubMsr_Key.Text, New_Msr_Form.Spec_Section.Text, New_Msr_Form.Complexity.Text, New_Msr_Form.Spec_Yr_Created.Text, _
                          New_Msr_Form.Spec_Yr_Removed.Text, New_Msr_Form.Denom_Only.Checked, New_Msr_Form.Report_Medicaid.Checked, _
                          New_Msr_Form.Report_Medicare.Checked, New_Msr_Form.Report_Ambetter.Checked)

        Msr_List.Refresh()
        Refresh()
        'Update form variables
        'New_Edit_Status = ""
        Msrs_Changed = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Encountered an error while creating the new version of an update measure. Due to the potentially dire consequences of this" _
               & "error, the program will now close. The HEDIS Measure XML should be restored from backup. Please see the error log for " _
               & "more details.", vbOKOnly, "Updated Measure Creation Error")
        MWin.Err.AddErr("Encountered an error while adding a new row to the QSI Populations DataGridView. Details: " & ex.Message, _
                        MWin.Err_Path & MWin.Err.DStamp & MWin.Log_Name)
        MWin.Close()
    End Try

    'Push the data back to the data table
    Fill_Tbl_From_List(Msr_List, MWin.HEDIS_Msr_List_Tbl, "Msr_List_View", MWin)

    'Create statuses if needed
    If Need_Statuses Then
        Create_Statuses(New_Msr_Form.Spec_Yr_Created.Text, New_Msr_Form.Msr_ID.Text, MWin)
    End If 'else nothing needs done

    'Re-sort
    Try
        Sort_Col = Msr_List.Columns("Msr_ID")
        Msr_List.Sort(Sort_Col, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Encountered an error trying re-sort the updated HEDIS Measures list to properly place the new/updated row. This is" _
               & " non-critical so the program will continue, but an error log entry has been created with more details.", vbOKOnly, _
               "Measure List Sort Error")
        MWin.Err.AddErr("Encountered an error while trying to sort the QSI Populations DataGridView. Details: " & ex.Message & _
                        Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Inner Exception: " & ex.InnerException.Message, MWin.Err_Path & MWin.Err.DStamp & MWin.Log_Name)
    End Try

    'Cancelled_New_Msr handles remaining clean-up needed so invoke it
    Cancelled_New_Msr()
End Sub


Public Sub Cancelled_New_Msr()
    '
    'Check if we should enable the Edit btn
    If Msr_List.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Edit_Btn.Enabled = True
    Else
        Edit_Btn.Enabled = False
    End If

    'Dispose of the form
    If Not (IsNothing(New_Msr_Form)) Then
        New_Msr_Form = Nothing
    End If 'else no form to dispose of
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: `VisibleChanged` probably isn't the event to hook. Too much code to review... Try a simple Save button to make your updates.

Comment: Exactly, thus moving the code out of the VisibleChanged event & the switch to using the specific methods (one for if Save is clicked, the other for Cancel that ignores the data on the entry form).